# Query grouped by calendar week / Issue: Date expands over more than one year

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2007

I have an SQL Query which calculates a quote of two sums. This quote shall be calculated on a weekly basis. Therefore is used `Datepart('ww', Date, 2, 2)` to get the calendar week.

This query worked fine during 2014, but now I am facing a problem.

The users choses with date pickers in a form from and to date which is then used in the where clause to only select relevant records.

If they chose a from date from past year (e.g. 2014) and a to date from this year my query shows irrelvant data, because it does not cosinder the year just the calendar week.

So, how group by calendar week AND only chose records from the correct year.

```
SELECT DatePart('ww',Date,2,2) AS WEEK, 
     Year(Workload_Date) AS [YEAR], 
    (SUM(Value1)+SUM(Value2))AS [Total1], 
    (SUM(Value3)+SUM(Value4)) AS [Total2],
    ((SUM(Value1)+SUM(Value2))/(SUM(Value3)+SUM(Value4))) AS [Quote]
FROM tbl
WHERE DatePart('ww',Date,2,2) Between DatePart('ww',FromDatePickerField,2,2) And DatePart('ww',ToDatePickerField,2,2)
GROUP BY DatePart('ww',Date,2,2), Year(Date)
ORDER BY Year(Date), DatePart('ww',Date,2,2);
```

The table contains one record per day.

```
Date       | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
01.01.2014 | 4      | 3      | 2      | 3      |
02.01.2014 | 4      | 3      | 9      | 3      |
03.01.2014 | 4      | 3      | 4      | 1      |
04.01.2014 | 4      | 3      | 1      | 3      |
...
01.01.2015 | 4      | 3      | 6      | 3      | 
02.01.2015 | 4      | 3      | 3      | 7      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could base your logic on `Week_Ending_date` instead of the week number and year, that way you could aggregate all you data on a weekly basis and let SQL handle the week/year detection logic.

Incase, you have a date range that spans 2 years, even then the calculations will be based on the week_ending_date and should work out correctly.

Something like...

```
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATE)), DATE)  AS WEEK_ENDING_DATE
        ,Year(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATE)), DATE)) AS [YEAR]
        ,(SUM(Value1) + SUM(Value2)) AS [Total1]
        ,(SUM(Value3) + SUM(Value4)) AS [Total2]
        ,((SUM(Value1) + SUM(Value2)) / (SUM(Value3) + SUM(Value4))) AS [Quote]
    FROM tbl
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATE)), DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, FromDatePickerField)), FromDatePickerField)
            AND DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, ToDatePickerField)), ToDatePickerField)
and date >= FromDatePickerField
and date <= ToDatePickerField
    GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATE)), DATE)    
    ORDER BY DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, DATE)), DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't completly understood the logic yet. Let's say a user choses a Wednesday as from date. Will this query select all records from Monday on? Same thing with the to date. User choses Wednesday again, will records until Sunday be selected?

Comment: You are right. You could limit the data for those cases though..Try the updated code.

Comment: Getting an error due to `dw` and `dd` in dateadd and in datepart. Needed to change `dw` to `'w'` and `dd` to `'d'`

Comment: Your query works so far, exept the calculation of the first and last week.

Comment: what's happening in the case of first and last week?

Comment: The second and thrid part of the where clause define the date of the relevant records. As described before, if user choses a wednesday as from date the where clause will exclude the records from Monday and Tuesday from calculation.

Comment: The initial impression i got was that you wanted to eliminate such dates. So if the User chooses Wednesday, do you want to include data for the dates for the same Week before Wednesday in your calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible solutions.

1) You stop the user while using the datepicker on the form whenever the years of the two datepickers are different. Maybe a MsgBox or something,

2) You change the to-DatePicker to the from-Year.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '01.11.2014'
DECLARE @tmpDate DATE = '12.02.2015'
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = (CASE WHEN Year(@MinDate) != Year(@tmpDate) THEN Convert(DATE, '31.12.' + Convert(VARCHAR(4), Year(@MinDate))) ELSE @tmpDate END)

SELECT @MinDate, @tmpDate, @MaxDate
```

Result :

```
minDate      tmpDate      maxDate
01.11.2014   12.02.2015   31.12.2014
```

Comment: If I do 1 there are still issues. If from and to date are in 2015, records from 2014 with the same calendar week are selected.

Comment: How about change the where-clause to 
`where date >= datepicker1` ?

Comment: Let's say a user choses a Wednesday as from date. Then I will miss the records from Monday and Tuesday. Same thing vice versa for to date.